# Electron app not asking for Camera and Microphone permission on macOS Monterey

Tags: macos, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager, macos-monterey

I have built an application of stack electron and reactjs. I am trying to access the camera and microphone from the application. But the app does not ask for permission when requested and also it does not show in the System Preferences -> Security and Privacy under camera and microphone.
Below are the versions I am using:

```
"electron": "^15.3.0",
"electron-builder": "^22.14.5",
"electron-devtools-installer": "^3.2.0",
"electron-notarize": "^1.1.1",
"electron-rebuild": "^3.2.3", 
"react": "^17.0.2"
```

Let me know what I am missing or needs to be changed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I also had this problem it worked fine in macOS Catalina but in Monterey sometimes it didn't.

I solved after reading this in the electron official documentation:

"If you plan to access the microphone or camera within your app using Electron's APIs, you'll also need to add the following entitlements"

```
<key>com.apple.security.device.audio-input</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.device.camera</key>
<true/>
```

To add the entitlements since you are using `electron-builder` there's a config that you can use in `package.json` to add it under `"mac"` you add this:

```
"extendInfo": {
        "NSMicrophoneUsageDescription": "Please give us access to your microphone",
        "NSCameraUsageDescription": "Please give us access to your camera",
        "com.apple.security.device.audio-input": true,
        "com.apple.security.device.camera": true
      },
```

And then you need to add the following lines to ask for media permissions:

```
const { systemPreferences } = require('electron')

const microphone = systemPreferences.askForMediaAccess('microphone');
const camera = systemPreferences.askForMediaAccess('camera');
```

Answer (score 4):

I would like to add extra information with the answer of [Caio Nakai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14451633/caio-nakai)
I'm having application crash issue with this fix also.

So I found the following fix. Under `mac` configuration please add the following property as `false`

```
"hardenedRuntime": false
```

Comment: Thanks for adding this information. I had the crash too before i used your fix.

Answer (score 2):

Peace and Kindness! This helped me:

systemPreferences.askForMediaAccess('microphone')
systemPreferences.askForMediaAccess('camera')

but only with it

https://www.electron.build/configuration/mas
https://github.com/electron/osx-sign/blob/main/entitlements/default.darwin.plist

entitlements String | “undefined” - The path to entitlements file for signing the app. build/entitlements.mas.plist will be used if exists (it is a recommended way to set). See this folder in osx-sign’s repository for examples. **Be aware that your app may crash if the right entitlements are not set like com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit for example on arm64 builds with Electron 20+.** See Signing and Notarizing macOS Builds from the Electron documentation for more information.