# getUserMedia() issue with permissions and DOMException: Could not start video source - Electron

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder

I'm creating an Electron app, and one of the things I want to do is stream the webcam to a video object. However, when I do getUserMedia(), the promise seems to not resolve, or something happens that causes a `DOMException: Could not start video source` error. I think this is a permissions error, as when I open Console I see one of the messages is `This app has crashed because it has a hardened runtime and attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without an entitlement indicating its intent to access this data.  The app must have the 'com.apple.security.device.camera' entitlement.`

I have tried to resolve this by requesting permissions with `navigator.permissions.query({name: 'camera'})`, however, it says that permissions are granted. When I check my Security and Privacy settings, however, my app is not listed under the Camera section. I think that the app somehow thinks it has permissions when it doesn't, and then unsuccessfully turns on the camera.

I also think this is a permissions issue because when I run the Electron app with `npm run start` (electron forge), it does seem to ask for permissions and successfully turns on the camera.

Here's my code that tries to start the camera:

```
let enableCam = function () {
navigator.permissions.query({name: 'camera'})
.then((permissionObj) => {
    console.log(permissionObj.state);
})
if (hasGetUserMedia()) {
    if(videoPlaying) {
        disableCam();
    }
    else {
        const constraints = {
            video: true,
            width: 224,
            height: 224
        };
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true}).then(stream => {
            video.srcObject = stream;
            webCamStream = stream;
            console.log("found stream");
            video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function () {
                videoPlaying = true;
                console.log("adding listener");
                enableCamButton.textContent = "Disable Webcam"
                captureImageButton.classList.remove("disabled");
            });
        }, err => console.log(err));
    }
} else {
    console.warn('getUserMedia() is not supported by your browser');
    enableCamButton.textContent = "Get User Media Not Supported";
}
```

When I create an app with `electron-builder --mac --arm64` and then run it, the console logs "granted" from the `permissionObj.state`.

I am running on an M1 Mac. I have tried building for x64 with `electron-builder --mac --x64`, and building for Windows x64 and running on a VM, with the same result - the camera does not start.

Edit - When I build my app for Apple Silicon and run it on my M1 Mac, the app does correctly request camera permissions, but when I build my app for x64 and run it through Rosetta, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72322847/10687680). It turns out electron-builder wasn't using my entitlements.mac.plist and instead I just added the `extendInfo` section to the build part of package.json.

```
      "extendInfo": {
        "NSMicrophoneUsageDescription": "Please give us access to your microphone",
        "NSCameraUsageDescription": "Please give us access to your camera",
        "com.apple.security.device.audio-input": true,
        "com.apple.security.device.camera": true
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a bunch of media-related settings that work for me in my NW project, in case they help...

**1**. Content Settings:

```
chrome.contentSettings.microphone.set({primaryPattern:'<all_urls>',setting:'allow'});  // allow|block|ask

chrome.contentSettings.camera.set({primaryPattern:'<all_urls>',setting:'allow'});      // allow|block|ask
```

In the manifest:

```
 "permissions": [
    "contentSettings", 
  ],
```

**2**. "Allow" attribute on the working iframe/window:

```
iframeID.setAttribute('allow','microphone; camera; encrypted-media;');
```

Comment: I'm not sure how I would apply the first and second to an Electron app, but I tried the third using "window.setAttribute(..);" which gave an error.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure how I would apply the first and second to an Electron
> app, but I tried the third using "window.setAttribute(..);" which gave
> an error. – William Li

I thought Electron enables you to create desktop web-apps in direct competition with Node-Webkit, and that the only major difference is that Electron kickstarts the app with javascript whereas we kickstart the app with a HTML file... no?

In which case you can call **Chromium API** functions in your Electron web-app, if you declare such libraries in you *manifest.json*... no?

If not Chromium APIs then surely Mozilla APIs, as in:

```
browser.contentSettings.microphone.set({primaryPattern:'<all_urls>',setting:'allow'});
```

Not even that?

Is there more than one product called “Electron”?

This is the Electron I'm talking about:

https://www.electronjs.org/

The very first line reads...

*“Electron embeds Chromium and Node.js to enable web developers to create desktop applications.”*

Have you only just started or using some other Electron?

Comment: You're right, I probably should have checked to see whether it would work. I guess I'm just inexperienced in using Chromium API functions. However, I'm not sure why but "chrome.contentSettings" seems to be undefined, is there something I need to change to be able to access it? I know I should add something to the manifest, but I don't have a manifest in my project.